# Ionic Templates not loading in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition even after installing 'Tools for Apache Cordova'

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have installed the 'Tools for Apache Cordova' by following this [link](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/) given out by Microsoft. However after doing so I am still not able to fetch the ionic templates from online as it still prompts me to install these tools.

I have tried:

- Restarting my Visual Studio.
- Running Visual Studio in Administrator Mode.

Update:

- I have also additionally now used 'Run Dependency Checker' option in
  the Tools and Extension Options. VS restarts without any reason and
  no output is displayed.
- Also, cleared the the Cordova cache. Still no luck.

Update 2:

I have tried to install the Ionic Templates from the VSIX link. Still the same error pops up prompting me to acquire 'Tools For Apache Cordova'. Here is the Install Log if it helps:

```
>14-09-2016 07:48:15 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
>14-09-2016 07:48:15 AM - -------------------------------------------
>14-09-2016 07:48:22 AM - Initializing Install...
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM - Extension Details...
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   Identifier         : IonicProjectTemplates
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   Name               : Ionic Project Templates for >Visual Studio
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   Author             : Tools for Apache Cordova
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   Version            : 1.0
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   Description        : Ionic1 Templates in JavaScript >and TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015. (Will require Visual Studio tools for >Apache Cordova)
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   Locale             : en-US
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   MoreInfoURL        : http://ionicframework.com/
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   InstalledByMSI     : False
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM - 
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   SignatureState     : Unsigned
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   Supported Products : 
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -           Version : [14.0,15.0)
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -           Version : [14.0,15.0)
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -           Version : [14.0,15.0)
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM - 
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   References         : 
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       ------------------------------------------------->------
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       Identifier   : MultiDeviceHybridApps.8BE90408->69F5-47A5-805A-8C4B01A54061
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       Name         : Visual Studio Tools for Apache >Cordova
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       Version      : [14.0.60527.5,15.0)
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       MoreInfoURL  : http://taco.visualstudio.com/en->us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -       Nested       : No
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM - 
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM - Signature Details...
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM -   Extension is not signed.
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM - 
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM - Searching for applicable products...
>14-09-2016 07:48:25 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio >Community 2015
>14-09-2016 07:48:39 AM - The extension with ID 'IonicProjectTemplates' is not >installed to Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015.
>14-09-2016 07:48:39 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 >Shell (Integrated)
>14-09-2016 07:48:39 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
>14-09-2016 07:48:44 AM - The following target products have been selected...
>14-09-2016 07:48:44 AM -   Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
>14-09-2016 07:48:44 AM - 
>14-09-2016 07:48:50 AM - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual >Studio Community 2015...
>14-09-2016 07:48:50 AM - Install Error : >Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingReferencesException: This >extension cannot be installed because the following references are missing:
>- Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova
>   at >Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.CheckForInstallB>lockers(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, IInstalledExtensionList >modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, Boolean isNestedExtension, Boolean& >olderVersionInstalled)
>   at >Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallInternal(>InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean perMachine, Boolean >isNestedExtension, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 vextensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList >modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, UInt64 >totalBytesToWrite, UInt64& totalBytesWritten)
>   at >Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.BeginInstall(IIn>stallableExtension installableExtension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation >asyncOp)
>   at >Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallWorker(II>nstallableExtension extension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

Another question which strikes me is that do I need to keep my VS up-to-date as in until Update 3. Right now I am on Update 1. Is that the trouble maker?

Seem to be running out of options, kindly help.

Comment: Are you able to create a blank Cordova project and build it successfully (to Ripple, for example)

Comment: Yes, I am able to do that.

Comment: Then, you downloaded the [Ionic templates VSIX from here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e44ba8b-a4c8-4106-b70e-00d63241a54a), and double clicked on it? It should have automatically installed in VS.

Comment: Did that as well. Pops up an error message saying it needs 'Tools for Apache Cordova' to be installed first. However I seem to have those tools already. I am planning on having VS update 2 as the next resort.

Comment: The update did the trick.That piece of Info is not clearly given in any document I read so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing the Visual Studio Update 3. By navigating here inside Visual Studio,

> Tools -> Extensions & Updates -> Updates-> Product Updates ->Update 3 for Visual Studio.

one can install the Update 3(if applicable).

Delving deeper, actually it is not the Visual Studio Update that did the trick but rather it was the **'Tools For Apache Cordova [Update 10]'** that comes along with it. Earlier versions had the **[Update 7]** installed by default. Hence be sure to tick that *checkbox* during per-installation configuration.

Once done, you can install the Ionic extensions from the [VSIX link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e44ba8b-a4c8-4106-b70e-00d63241a54a) or from **New Project** screen as well([follow this guide](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/)).